# a question about vscode remote python develop

Tags: python, vscode-remote, anaconda3

“I’m doing Python development on a server using Remote-SSH with VSCode. However, I encountered a problem when configuring the Python interpreter. I found that when executing the
`pip install` 
command, the installed packages were being placed in the Conda base environment instead of the one I activated. This has me very confused, as I’ve tried configuring the settings file and the project’s default interpreter, but nothing seems to work. To install packages correctly, I have to use `python -m pip install`. I used the `pip -V` command to check the location of pip and found that it was in the base environment, and none of my attempts have been able to change its location.

I was wondering if there is a way to fix this issue so that I can use `pip install` instead of `python -m pip install` to install packages.”

Comment: First of all, **stop using `pip install`. For the love of god please just use `python -m pip`.** If you really want to use the old `pip install` you need to modify your PATH variable and remove the directory of your old pip installation and add the new pip installation.

Comment: “Thank you for your answer. I’m a beginner in Python and could you tell me what the difference is between the two approaches and why the latter one is better?”

Comment: The latter is better because it guarantees that the packages will be installed to the site-packages directory that's in the path of the Python interpreter that you're using. Most systems have multiple Python interpreters installed and it's pretty easy to use a `pip` which is associated with a different interpreter. [so] is littered with questions of the form: "I installed packages with `pip` but `python` says 'ModuleNotFoundError'..."